# Near identical code producing different results. TIME modual

Tags: python, time, replit

I am using TIME for the first time and wanted to make a basic timer. I ran this code completely on its own:

```
import time
start = int(time.time())
answered = "No"
while int(time.time()) - 2 < start:  
  if input("What's 1 + 1?") == 2:
    print("Correct")
  else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

This code's execution gives you 2 seconds to answer as many times as you want, once 2s is up you can no longer answer, this was made just so I could practice using the TIME module and has no greater purpose.

However, when I tried to implement the TIME module into a game I am working on:

```
start = int(time.time())
hits = 0
while int(time.time()) - start != time:
 #COMBAT MECHANICS#
```

I have only included a tiny snippet of code as this is the only times time is mentioned in the code so the only relevant part for this error.

When this code is ran I receive the message: "UnboundLovalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment"

Time is imported at the beginning of the code as it was in the practice. The only difference is this is within a function, but I don't see how that should influence the behaviour of the code.

Please can someone help me fix this.

Comment: You seem to be using the name `time` for both the imported module and a local variable.  It can't be both things at the same time...

Comment: _The only difference is this is within a function, but I don't see how that should influence the behaviour of the code._ this COULD have HUGE difference, due to scope. Please, post [mre], incl. full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @jasonharper you changed your logic in the second example and in the process misused `time` in your `while` statement.  Keeping your second example's logic in line with your first example's logic (assuming that is your goal) you would want to do something like this:

```
start = int(time.time())
hits = 0
while int(time.time()) - 2 < start:
 #COMBAT MECHANICS#
```